# Al logear correctamente no me envía la pantalla dashboard desde vuejs consumiendo api de laravel

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

Estoy realizando un login personalizado con vuejs3 y laravel 9 en el mismo proyecto. Al ingresar correctamente no me dirige a la pantalla de dashboard. Debugeando por consola me muestra que ingreso correctamente y la ruta cambia correctamente pero no la pantalla porque se queda en el mismo formulario de login.

Este es el formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ingreso los datos correctamente pasa esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo `api.php` de rutas laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'check']);
```

Controlador personalizado `LoginController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function check(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'acceso' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('acceso','password'))) {
            $user = User::where('acceso', $request->acceso)->first();

            $generarToken = $user->createToken('Token Personal');
            $token = $generarToken->plainTextToken;

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'Ok',
                'message' => "Ingreso con exito",
                'token'=>$token
            ],200);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => "No autorizado"

        ],401);
    }
```

Este es el archivo `main.blade` donde enlazo vuejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Dashboard - SB Admin</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/plantilla.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>

<body class="sb-nav-fixed">

    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <script src="{{asset('js/plantilla.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')


</body>

</html>
```

El archivo `app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from '../src/routes'
import App from '../src/components/Login.vue';

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Archivo `bootstrap.js`

```
import 'bootstrap';

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Archivo `Login.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2 align="center">Login</h2>

      <form @submit.prevent="LoginData">
        <div class="form-group" align="left">
          <label>acceso</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            v-model="usuario.acceso"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="acceso"
          />
          <span v-if="errors.acceso" class="error">{{ errors.acceso[0] }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" align="left">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            v-model="usuario.password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <span v-if="errors.password" class="error">{{
            errors.password[0]
          }}</span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
   
<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  setup() {
    const errors = reactive({
      acceso: null,
      password: null,
    });

    const usuario = reactive({
      acceso: "",
      password: "",
    });

    const router = useRouter();

    const LoginData = () => {
      console.log("paso");
      errors.acceso = null;
      errors.password = null;

      axios
        .post("http://gestion-calidad.test/api/login", usuario)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data);
          localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
          router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            Object.assign(errors, error.response.data.errors);
          } else {
            Object.assign(errors, error.response);
          }
        });
    };

    return {
      usuario,
      errors,
      LoginData,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.error {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Archivo `Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoggedIn">
    <Cabezera />
    <div id="layoutSidenav">
      <Menu />
      <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
        <main>
          <div class="container">
            <router-view />
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Menu from "./components/layouts/Menu.vue";
import Cabezera from "./components/layouts/Cabezera.vue";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  components: {
    Menu,
    Cabezera,
    Footer,
  },
  setup() {
    const isLoggedIn = computed(() => {
      // You should replace this with your actual authentication check
      return localStorage.getItem("token") !== null;
    });

    return {
      isLoggedIn,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

archivo `routes.js` de rutas en vuejs

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.vue'

const routes = [ 
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard
    }
];

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

Comment: No llevo mucho con laravel y tengo unas dudas/observaciones; las rutas de tu web app no deberían ir en el `routes/web.php` hasta donde se el `api.php` es para cuando creas una API con laravel; y la segunda es que, no veo en tu `function check()` hagas el return a una vista, si haces el json y es lo que te muestra en la consola pero no de una vista. Saludos.

Comment: @Artes Hola, por eso utilizo vuejs para consumir la api de laravel.